# Explanation for Java (palindrom string) and method next();

Tags: java

I want to know more about how next method work and Java utill scanner if someone can help me...

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Unesite string za proveru: ");

```
    if(palindrom(s.next()))
        System.out.println("String je palindrom");
    else
        System.out.println("String nije palindrom");

    s.close();
```

what does next do? and how exactly scanner working also what means method close(); ??

Comment: next() reads the next token in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

next

```
public String next()
```

Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matchesthe delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Specified by:next in interface IteratorReturns:the next tokenThrows:NoSuchElementException

1 - if no more tokens are availableIllegalStateException
2- if this scanner is closedSee Also:Iterator

example :-

```
sc = "hello world"
1st time sc.next() output will be "hello"
2nd time sc.next() output will be "world"
```

close

```
public void close()
```

Closes this scanner. 
If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close methodwill be invoked. If this scanner is already closed then invoking thismethod will have no effect.

Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner hasbeen closed will result in an IllegalStateException.
Specified by:close in interface CloseableSpecified by:close in interface AutoCloseable

Answer (score -2):

`Scanner` is a class that parses, and in some cases converts inputs. It uses whitespace as its default delimiter between tokens.

`Scanner.next` is a method that finds and returns the next token, if there is one.

`Scanner.close` is a method that releases the resource that the `Scanner` object is holding, such as an open file.